# Spring Boot project can't find Hibernate.cfg.xml when run as executable jar

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I see that issues with the hibernate.cfg.xml not being found when SessionFactory is being set up is a somewhat common occurrence, but my question here is somewhat specific. My project works fine when run in Eclipse, even when I move the hibernate.cfg.xml around; I can leave it at the source level and do this:

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
```

Or I can move it to a different location and define it this way:

```
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("/path/to/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Both ways work in Eclipse. However, when I build an executable jar to run the application elsewhere, when it launches it complains:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation 
failed.org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not 
locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate 
cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
```

I understand (or I think I do) that the reason for this is that the hibernate.cfg.xml isn't getting included in the jar itself and so even when the path is defined it can't find it but am not sure how to fix it. I think if I can get the file into the jar then it may work (maybe the classpath also needs an entry for this?) but I'm actually not sure how to do so.

Comment: Is it a Maven project?

Comment: This is Spring Boot, running in Eclipse. I've been using Gradle to do the builds.

Answer (score 0):

It mainly depends on whether you are using a framework or not and if yes the which framework you are using. If you are not using any framework then keeping hibernate.cfg.xml file in your root path can be fine. But Because of urge in standardising the coding process, frameworks usually expect the file in your resources folder.But in your case you should give the path to that configuration file not relative to the root folder but entire path.

Comment: Thanks for the response Deadpool - this is in a Java Spring Boot framework. Currently, I have the file in my resources folder and am just calling it like this: configuration.configure("Hibernate.cfg.xml"); However, when I package it into an executable jar and kick that off, it can't find the file.  When you say the entire path, how far back do you mean, to the workspace folder, or all the way to C:?

Comment: is your resources folder marked as resources root? and yes it is way back to C. Usually it works if you mark your resources marked as resources root.

Comment: If I look at the Build Path properties in Eclipse under 'Source' I have the /main/resources folder there, as well as a second one I was using /main/java/resources in an attempt to get the file to be sucked into the jar when it was built.

Comment: you should use that main/resources folder for storing all those cfg.xml and .hbm files.

Comment: That's the way it works best in Eclipse...the problem is that when I do that, and then run from an executable jar, it throws an error saying it can't find the hibernate.cfg.xml file. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Ok!! it's wierd. Can i know the commands that u used to build and run that jar.

Comment: Sure thing - from the command line, at the top level of the project, I issue the command 'gradle clean build jar', then to run it, I go to the directory where the jar is and use the command 'java -jar jarname.jar'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using absolute path here:

```
configuration.configure("/path/to/hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Instead of that you should use classpath loader. Something like this :

```
Resource r = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml")
String path = r.getURI().getPath();
configuration.configure(path);
```

This should work after packaging jar.

Comment: Hm, when I do that I see it does generate the path, but then when it tries to run (even in Eclipse) it fails saying it can't find the file (it's there, I can see it) Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/C:/Users/James/workspace/SpringTinker/bin/main/hibernate.cfg.xml]

Comment: can u replace first slash?
    path = path.replaceFirst("/", "");

Comment: I gave that a try, but it comes back with the same error (minus the preceding slash). It's weird, the file is there.